Transition: transform is acting weird when on different zoom level
I have a html dashboard script that include a compass , red arrow and a ship.
Scenario :
When the api provide value heading, the red arrow and the ship will rotate based on the direction given.
For example, if the heading value is 90, the red arrow and the ship will rotate to the given direction/degree.
Problem:
After I add transition for ship and the red arrow, the ship and the arrow transition is smooth, but when i adjust my browser zoom level to 80% it will goes beyond the compass and rotate like crazy when rotating goes beyond the compass like the image below. The rotation is working normally when its on any zoom level

/* Add this CSS to enable smooth transitions */
#ship {
  transition: transform 1s ease-in-out;
}

#compass polygon {
  transition: transform 1s ease-in-out;
}

Demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/j9w7k63n/
Can try to adjust zoom level to trigger the problem.
